Using list of tables and list of figures in Quarto to reference output of code chunks
I want to generate a PDF thesis document that has a list of tables and a list of figures at the beginning of the Quarto document. It does not seem to be a straightforward way to do it. I saw this post, which gives some guidance.
My question:
Is there a way to automatically add tables (from gt, gtsummary, or flextable) generated from code chunks to the list of tables? Same question regarding plots.

If I'm not mistaken all tables and figures which have captions will be added to list of tables/figures.

How to add a caption to the gt table created inside the R chunk?

as chunk option, ex. #| tbl-cap: Long table caption . The same for generated figures: #| fig-cap: Population and population .... Details in https://quarto.org/docs/reference/cells/cells-knitr.html

This solved it! Thank you. Please post the answer so I can choose it as the best answer

Let's summarize it. To have list of tables / list of figures in the document we have to add lof: true and/or lot: true in format section of the header. It corresponds to LaTeX \listoftables, \listoffigures macros. To have the entries in the list, the table/figure has to have caption. For those generated tables/plots generated with r/python, we can use fig-cap and tbl-cap options of chunks.
---
title: "Untitled"
format: 
  pdf:
    lof: true
    lot: true
---

## Quarto

```{r}
plot(1)
```

```{r}
#| fig-cap: Figure caption

plot(2)
```

```{r}
#| fig-cap: Another plot

plot(3, pch = 3)
```

And the same for tables

```{r}
#| echo: false
#| tbl-cap: Table caption

cars |>
  head() |>
  kableExtra::kbl() |> 
  kableExtra::kable_classic_2()
```

Which produces desired output:

